# Different settings for Midnight Commander running as root and as regular user

Tags: sudo, settings, midnight-commander

Is it possible to have some settings for Midnight Commander when run as user

```
$ mc
```

and some different settings (e.g. skin) when run as root?

```
$ sudo mc
```

The motivation is that it is immediately recognizable whether I'm using mc as root or as a regular user so that I'm aware of the "power" I have.

I tried to change the skin in Options -> Appereance and then saving the setup by Options -> Save setup both when `mc` and `sudo mc` but the settings are always just the last ones saved, no matter how the `mc` was started (both for "viewing" the settings and saving the settings).

Comment: Have you tried invoking sudo with the -H (--set-home) switch `sudo -H mc`?

Comment: "sudo su - -c mc" -  not entirely sure now, but I think this may also be a solution (not necessarily the simplest one though)

Comment: @steeldriver Great, this works! It's a pity that I must always include the ``-H`` switch though. You can post it as an answer and I will probably accept it (after some time if nobody comes up with some better magic).

Comment: Sorry - that should be sudo su - -c mc. But anyway steeldriver's solution is simpler and works, so all good. cheers

Answer (score 5):

If you invoke sudo with the `-H` switch, `mc` should read/write its settings to root's home directory `/root/.config/mc` instead of writing them to your own home directory `~/.config/mc`. From `man sudo`:

```
 -H, --set-home
             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
             variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
             password database entry.
```

Comment: Just wandering, would it cause problems (in the rest of the system) to alias ``sudo`` as ``sudo -H``?

Comment: @JanŽegklitz I don't know, however, it might be better to use sudo's own configuration settings to achieve that e.g. via `always_set_home` rather than an alias: see `man sudoers`.

Comment: @JanŽegklitz or perhaps safer, just create an alias for sudo mc e.g. `alias smc='sudo -H mc'`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did right away. I was just wandering why the ``-H`` is not set by default and what would it mean if it was.